# Task being marked as RanToCompletion at await, when still Running

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm still getting up to speed with async & multi threading. I'm trying to monitor when the Task I Start is still running (to show in a UI).  However it's indicating that it is RanToCompletion earlier than I want, when it hits an await, even when I consider its Status as still Running.

Here is the sample I'm doing.  It all seems to be centred around the await's.  When it hits an await, it is then marked as RanToCompletion.

I want to keep track of the **main Task** which starts it all, in a way which indicates to me that it is still running *all the way to the end* and only RanToCompletion when it is all done, including the repo call and the WhenAll.

How can I change this to get the feedback I want about the tskProdSeeding task status?

My Console application Main method calls this:

```
Task tskProdSeeding;
tskProdSeeding = Task.Factory.StartNew(SeedingProd, _cts.Token);
```

Which the runs this:

```
private async void SeedingProd(object state)
{
    var token = (CancellationToken)state;

    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        int totalSeeded = 0;

        var codesToSeed = await _myRepository.All().ToListAsync(token);

        await Task.WhenAll(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            foreach (var code in codesToSeed)
            {
                if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int seedCountByCode = await _myManager.SeedDataFromLive(code);

                        totalSeeded += seedCountByCode;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _logger.InfoFormat(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }, token));

        Thread.Sleep(30000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `async void` the outer task can't tell when the task is finished, you need to use `async Task` instead.

Second, once you do switch to `async Task`, `Task.Factory.StartNew` can't handle functions that return a `Task`, you need to switch to `Task.Run(`

```
tskProdSeeding = Task.Run(() => SeedingProd(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
```

Once you do both of those changes you will be able to await or do a `.Wait()` on `tskProdSeeding` and it will properly wait till all the work is done before continuing.

Please read "[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)" to learn more about not doing `async void`.

Please read "[StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)" to learn more about why you should not be using  StartNew the way you are using it.

---

P.S. In `SeedingProd` you should switch it to use `await Task.Delay(30000);` insetad of `Thread.Sleep(30000);`, you will then not tie up a thread while it waits. If you do this you likely could drop the

```
tskProdSeeding = Task.Run(() => SeedingProd(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
```

and just make it

```
tskProdSeeding = SeedingProd(_cts.Token);
```

because the function no-longer has a blocking call inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that you need a second thread (`Task.Run` or `StartNew`) at all. It looks like the bulk of the work is I/O-bound and if you're doing it asynchronously and using `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`, then [there is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) consumed by those operations and your UI shouldn't freeze. The first thing anyone new to async needs to understand is that it's not the same thing as multithreading. The latter is all about consuming more threads, the former is all about consuming fewer. Focus on eliminating the *blocking* and you shouldn't need a second thread.

As others have noted, `SeedingProd` needs to return a `Task`, not `void`, so you can observe its completion. I believe your method can be reduced to this:

```
private async Task SeedingProd(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        int totalSeeded = 0;

        var codesToSeed = await _myRepository.All().ToListAsync(token);

        foreach (var code in codesToSeed)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;

            try
            {
                int seedCountByCode = await _myManager.SeedDataFromLive(code);
                totalSeeded += seedCountByCode;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.InfoFormat(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        await Task.Dealy(30000);
    }
}
```

Then simply call the method, without awaiting it, and you'll have your task.

```
Task mainTask = SeedingProd(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `async` on a method, it compiles into a state machine with a Task, so `SeedingProd` does not run synchronously, but acts as a Task even if returns `void`. So when you call `Task.Factory.StartNew(SeedingProd)` you start a task that kick off another task - that's why the first one finishes immediately before the second one. All you have to do is add the `Task` return parameter instead of `void`:

```
private async Task SeedingProdAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
...
}
```

and call it as simply as this:

```
Task tskProdSeeding = SeedingProdAsync(_cts.Token);
```

Comment: Async functions run synchronously up until the first `await` that was not complete at the point you called it. Because of this, just removing the task factory is risky, he still has the `Thread.Sleep(30000);`, if both `ToListAsync` and `WhenAll` complete syncronously you will cause the thread that called `SeedingProdAsync` to block for 30 seconds, if you are going to drop the factory (and not replace it with a `Taks.Run(`) you must swap out the sleep for a `Task.Delay`.

Comment: I bet `Thread.Sleep` was added just for the test to track the completion and is not a part of the real code

Comment: I don't think so, it is inside a `while` loop, I bet the sleep is there because he wants the task to be run every 30 seconds till it is canceled.

Comment: Or switch to `Task.Delay` and await it.

Comment: I think Task.Delay even better, as far as I remember 'long running' just creates a new thread.